# What's mutual exclusivity in meta-learning?

Tags: terminology, papers, meta-learning

What do we mean by mutual exclusivity of tasks?

This work ([E Pan, 21](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.09819)) and this one ([M Yin, 20](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=BklEFpEYwS)) state that most classification meta-learning algorithms fail for non-mutually exclusive tasks as the model may over-fit to a task, and no model can solve all the tasks at once (respectively).

I had trouble understanding the exact meaning of a "task" in meta classification here. [[E Pan, 21](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=BklEFpEYwS)] uses "task" synonymously with "new class", while [[M Yin, 20](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=BklEFpEYwS)] states "...prior work uses a per-task random assignment of image classes to N-way classification labels". However, some priors on few-shot learning [[S. Hugo, 17](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJY0-Kcll)], and [[Y Wang, 19](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05046.pdf)] agree with [FFLab's, (20) description](https://meta-learning.fastforwardlabs.com/) of "task" which I found more clear:

> The number of classes (N) in the support set defines a task as an N-class classification task or N-way task, and the number of labeled examples in each class (k) corresponds to k-shot, making it an N-way, k-shot learning problem.

Where the support set $D_s$ here is part of the meta training data $D$ which comprises a support and test set $D_t$  $D = <D_s, D_t>$ [[Weng, 18](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/11/30/meta-learning.html)].

However, even with a better understanding of what a "task" is, I still couldn't get what constitutes mutually exclusive tasks.